# Close form after loading another one

Tags: c#, forms, oop, loading

I'm tying to develop simple app with 1 main form and few sub forms.

Firstly I have created loading form (Loading form has 2 IMGs and 1 Label, 1 IMG I loading GIF), and that form works only for a few sec. Next up I have created another form (That form should be login form). Now I need to Close first form after second form is loaded or displayed. Here is code from my first form:

```
public partial class Loading : Form
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public Loading()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 10, 10));
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int loading_time = rnd.Next(2500, 4200);
        aTimer.Interval = loading_time;
        aTimer.SynchronizingObject = this; //////////////
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

    }




    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       // New Form run 1st try
        login form2 = new login();
        form2.ShowDialog();

      // New Form run 2nd try
        Application.Run(new login());

      // Loading form closing 1st try
      this.Close();

         // Loading form closing 2nd try
      Loading.Close();
```

I also tried to close first form with a button on the second form but that didn't work.
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know what happens when you run this code.

Comment: @Grant - I don't know, I tried to stop timer but that didn't help.

Comment: @zmarks22 Loading starts, and afterwards simply brakes down with unexpected something : `code`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Loading' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`code`

Comment: @MarkHall That is true but it won't even close my entire application. I tried to change status of that form to "NOT MAIN" but I don't know how...

Comment: Please do not post that has nothing to do with the question. I don't see where the results of CreateRoundRectRgn method are used in this code. It only makes it harder to read it. Especially when you read it in small window with scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access controls from threads other then threads that created it.

`OnTimedEvent` is called in thread other than your main thread.

Edit:
Try this

`aTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;`

This should make the `OnTimedEvend` run on thread that created the form.

Comment: But I can't close that form from another form. I wrote that I tried to close first form by button in another form

Comment: Still getting same unexpected error... TNX for trying

Comment: Please clean the code as I described under you question. Then show stacktrace (formatted) with line numbers.

Comment: And where is the code I told you to try? And where is the stacktrace?